# how to set adminTimeout value with @EmbeddedKafka Annotation (junit5)?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

While using parallel gradle tests (org.gradle.parallel=true) to minimize overall test-execution time with junit5 and the @EmbeddedKafka annotation (I need to do integration-tests for > 20 different kafka-based micro-services; using parallel-testing allows me to divide execution-time by a factor 10), I started experimenting timeout exceptions as part of the createTopics method of EmbeddedKafkaBroker.
This problem could be easily remediated by setting up a custom value for the adminTimeout member of EmbeddedKafkaBroker...The problem is I can't see how to achieve this while using junit5 and @EmbeddedKafka annotation...any suggestion ?
thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker`:

```
/**
 * Set the timeout in seconds for admin operations (e.g. topic creation, close).
 * Default 30 seconds.
 * @param adminTimeout the timeout.
 * @since 2.2
 */
public void setAdminTimeout(int adminTimeout) {
```

is just not exposed into an `@EmbeddedKafka`.

Feel free to raise a GH issue so we will consider to add it in the future.

As a workaround you can setup such an embedded broker manually:
private static EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;

```
@BeforeAll
static void setup() {
    embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, true, topic1, topic2);
    embeddedKafka.setAdminTimeout(100);
    embeddedKafka.afterPropertiesSet();
}

@AfterAll
static void tearDown() {
    embeddedKafka.destroy();
}
```

Comment: As per your suggestion, I created request #2059 under GH spring-kafka project.
Thanks again for your feedback, Artem !

Comment: You might also want to explore using a single broker for the entire test suite https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#using-the-same-brokers-for-multiple-test-classes